# Rails: SCSS not being rendered correctly using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, render, sass

https://gist.github.com/2597515

Note I used a html to haml converter. The sidebar partial is overlapping the main container, and the padding is messed up in some areas. Could this be because of my haml? Let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could definitely be because of your Haml code. The converter is not perfect and will never be perfect. You'll have to check the generated code by hand.

Comment: Alright well let me ask this: Even though the haml was generated, it should all be correct. I mean, why wouldn't it? So in other words, if it IS an issue, it would be an issue with the indentation?

Comment: I don't know the details, but the converter doesn't know all the nuances of HTML. It might think that one HAML representation produces the same html, but it doesn't. HTML is actually really hard to parse correctly. Some HTML are tricks/side-effects aren't even possible in HAML.